# Sequlize Query get last added value

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I am using Sequlize. I have a table `status_config` in this table I have a column create_time as timestamp( `2021-06-02 12:04:52.293977`).  Now I need to query on this table and get the latest value created on this table.

```
status_config.findOne({ where: created_time **need to implement here to get last added value})
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `order` by `[['createdAt', 'desc']]`

```
let last_status_config = await status_config.findOne({
    order:[['createdAt', 'desc']]
});
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(last_status_config)))
```

Output

```
{ id: 19, name: 'test_last', password: null, confirmation: null }
```